# How to clone multiple SVN locations into a single Git repo

Tags: git, svn

I've got an SVN repo that I want to move specific parts to a Git repo. Let's say the SVN repo has many directories under trunk but the only two I want to move across are:

- trunk\projectA
- trunk\projectB

I've successfully moved projectA by running the commands:

```
git svn clone http://svn-url.com/repo-name/trunk/projectA
git push git-url.com:/repo-name.git master
```

However, trying to run:

```
git svn clone http://svn-url.com/repo-name/trunk/projectB
```

Fails with the message:

```
svn-remote.svn.url already set: http://svn-url.com/repo-name/trunk/projectA wanted to set to: http://svn-url.com/repo-name/trunk/projectB
```

Anyone know how I can migrate multiple directories under trunk into a single Git repo?

I'm not sure if it matters but the Git repo is hosted in GitHub and the SVN repo is hosted by beanstalkapp.com.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--ignore-paths` [option](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html) to exclude directories that you don't want to have in your git repository:

```
git svn clone \
--ignore-paths='<regex>' \
http://svn-url.com/repo-name/trunk
```